# fail2ban error: fail2ban-client: ERROR No file(s) found for glob

Tags: fail2ban

I installed a server inside docker: logs are mounted in a shared volume with host.
In the host i m checking a log file with fail2ban.

I can't understand why fail2ban gives this error

```
fail2ban error: fail2ban-client: ERROR  No file(s) found for glob <path>
```

The path for the file exists.

If i pass backend =systemd  ... it works Why?

I think could be a permission(group permission is docker).

Comment: I found the solution: backend = systemd. I dont know why.